# How do I define an embedded generic structure to return a reference to an array?

Tags: generics, rust

I am trying to write own generic structure that will be holding a byte array.
The idea is to have a structure that contains 2 structures, and each will hold some binary data.

```
use std::ops::Index;
    
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Header<T: AsRef<[u8]>> {
    format: T,
}
    
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Data<T: AsRef<[u8]>> {
    bytes: T,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Request<T: AsRef<[u8]>> {
    header: Header<T>,
    body: Data<T>,
}

impl<T: AsRef<[u8]>> Request<T>
where
T: Index<std::ops::Range<usize>, Output = T>,
{
    pub fn new(bytes: T) -> Request<T> {
        Request {
            header: Header{format: bytes[0..1]},
            body: Data{bytes: bytes[1..5]},
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let bytes: [u8; 5] = [0x00, 0xFF, 0xEE, 0xDD, 0xCC]; // create array [u8; 5]
    let request = Request::new(bytes);  // expected array `[u8; 5]`, found slice?

    println!("Request: {:?}", request);
}
```

Now when I try to compile this code, compiler will output the following error.

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<[u8; 5] as Index<std::ops::Range<usize>>>::Output == [u8; 5]`
  --> src/main.rs:34:16
   |
23 |     pub fn new(bytes: T) -> Request<T> {
   |     ---------------------------------- required by `Request::<T>::new`
...
34 |     let request = Request::new(bytes);  // expected array `[u8; 5]`, found slice?
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected array `[u8; 5]`, found slice
   |
   = note: expected array `[u8; 5]`
              found slice `[u8]`
```

I started thinking that this message is probably not pointing the real reason why this code is not compiling, as `let bytes: [u8; 5] = [0x00, 0xFF, 0xEE, 0xDD, 0xCC];` is an array according to the definition:

> A fixed-size array, denoted [T; N], for the element type, T, and the
> non-negative compile-time constant size, N.
>
> There are two syntactic forms for creating an array:
>
> A list with each element, i.e., [x, y, z]. A repeat expression [x; N],
> which produces an array with N copies of x. The type of x must be
> Copy.

I believe there is something wrong with my new method where I am slicing bytes into 2 parts, but cannot find a way to get this code to compile.
I would appreciate some help how to create such construct in generic way in Rust, not sure if my approach is good.

Comment: I think the type mismatch is in the return type of the index operation; I'd assume arrays implement Index with a range object as the indexing thing and return a _slice_, not an array of exactly length 5.

Comment: Really the problem is that `T` gets "fixed" to be `[u8; 5]` because arrays of different length really are different types...

Comment: But even if you fix the type stuff, there's the issue that you can't just store slices "raw" in structs: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=72c0081890f4dd1037a55b6b27a633cb

Comment: You might want to have your structs _reference_ the source byte array instead by storing `&[u8]`s instead of `T`s -- see [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5175c0e16a976a21487694d5a88a2840). Why do you need the structs to be generic?

Comment: As general advice, if you do run into problems with generics it's often a good idea to start with something concrete and then step by step make it generic.